# How to get JSON data from HTML form with backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am creating a dynamic form in a Backbone.js view. I want to get all the JSON data from the form in my view without using jQuery. Is there any way to get the data?

For example: When You check the checkbox, I only want the data for the checked field.

```html
<table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th>{{labels.selectImage}}</th>
                      <th>{{labels.nameVisibleToShop}}</th>
                      <th>{{labels.sourceCode}}</th>
                      <th>{{labels.pricePerItem}}</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr id ="school-imageId-{{categoryImage.cmsId}}">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control mz-embrodiary-enable"/></td>
    <td><img width="40px" src="{{categoryImage.imageUrl}}" /></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="{{labels.nameVisibleToShop}}" disabled/>
        <span class="mz-validationmessage hidden" data-mz-validationmessage-for="name">{{labels.genericRequired}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="sourceCode" class="form-control" placeholder="{{labels.sourceCode}}" disabled/>
        <span class="mz-validationmessage hidden" data-mz-validationmessage-for="name">{{labels.genericRequired}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="{{labels.enterPrice}}" disabled/>
        <span class="mz-validationmessage hidden" data-mz-validationmessage-for="price">{{labels.genericRequired}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr id ="school-imageId-{{categoryImage.cmsId}}">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control mz-embrodiary-enable"/></td>
    <td><img width="40px" src="{{categoryImage.imageUrl}}" /></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="{{labels.nameVisibleToShop}}" disabled/>
        <span class="mz-validationmessage hidden" data-mz-validationmessage-for="name">{{labels.genericRequired}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="sourceCode" class="form-control" placeholder="{{labels.sourceCode}}" disabled/>
        <span class="mz-validationmessage hidden" data-mz-validationmessage-for="name">{{labels.genericRequired}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="{{labels.enterPrice}}" disabled/>
        <span class="mz-validationmessage hidden" data-mz-validationmessage-for="price">{{labels.genericRequired}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr id ="school-imageId-{{categoryImage.cmsId}}">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control mz-embrodiary-enable"/></td>
    <td><img width="40px" src="{{categoryImage.imageUrl}}" /></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="{{labels.nameVisibleToShop}}" disabled/>
        <span class="mz-validationmessage hidden" data-mz-validationmessage-for="name">{{labels.genericRequired}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="sourceCode" class="form-control" placeholder="{{labels.sourceCode}}" disabled/>
        <span class="mz-validationmessage hidden" data-mz-validationmessage-for="name">{{labels.genericRequired}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="{{labels.enterPrice}}" disabled/>
        <span class="mz-validationmessage hidden" data-mz-validationmessage-for="price">{{labels.genericRequired}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
```

Comment: Why without jQuery? Backbone is using jQuery already.

Comment: What do you mean by _"JSON data"_? You mean just an object with the data or you want an actual JSON string?

Comment: @EmileBergeron JSON data means form data.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Actually my form field are created dynamically. so i don't know to get data from fields and save in my collection. please help

Comment: You'll have to provide a [mcve] and a clearer description. As it stands, it's unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: You may want to look at the Backbone.stickit library. It provides 2-way data binding between models and the view, which is great for forms.